# How to convert a RTF-text in MySQL to plain text?

Tags: mysql, rtf

I'm working on a database migration script for a MySQL-database and writing StoredProcedures for that purpose.
In one of the tables of the old database to migrate there are columns with RTF-texts.
I have looked for a StoredProcedure or Function to convert the RTF-text to plain text, but found nothing really useful.
Is there a StoredProcedure or a library by which i can convert these RTF-texts?

Here an example for one of these RTF-texts:

```
{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\deftab720{\fonttbl{\f0\fswiss MS Sans Serif;}{\f1\froman\fcharset2 Symbol;}{\f2\fnil VersaPlusSM;}{\f3\froman Times New Roman;}{\f4\fnil\fprq2 VersaPlusSM;}{\f5\fswiss\fprq2 MS Sans Serif;}}
 {\colortbl\red0\green0\blue0;\red255\green0\blue0;}
 \deflang1031\horzdoc{\*\fchars }{\*\lchars }\pard\plain\f4\fs40\b Konstanzpr\'fcfung nach \'a716 R\'f6V - DIN 6868-157\plain\f2\fs20 
 \par }
```

Comment: i need same...did you get any solution?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind writing a little Java, you could use JDBC to extract the RTF from your database and [RTF Parser Kit](https://github.com/joniles/rtfparserkit) to convert to plain text, after which you can update/insert the result of the conversion.